# How do you stop Chome from always redirecting to https (not desired)?

Tags: node.js, angular, google-chrome

Somehow my environment has been changed such that every Angular project I enter and run ng serve command on now redirects to the https port.  Even if I use --ssl false option, it still redirects to https.

I suspect that this is some change to the node environment.  I've looked through environmental variables and combed the net trying to find ways of turning SSL OFF, but all I find are articles that speak of turning it ON.   Most of them are VERY intentional changes to the Angular.json file or they are use a command that specifies the certificate and key.

If you could point me to the right documentation or put me on the right path, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: That has most likely nothing to do with angular, but with your computer's settings.

Comment: @chrispbacon You are correct. It ended up being a company HSTS policy change to Chrome that was redirecting back to HTTPS.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the case of our company - it appears that it's related to a domain policy probably put in place by our IT Department.

One clue is the Network Traffic in chrome debugger: 
307 Internal Redirect 
and the response header has:
Non-Authoritative-Reason: HSTS

Try going to: chrome://net-internals/#hsts and if you have authority, deleting the policy for "localhost."

If you can't delete this, then I advice following the steps from this article which also worked for me: 
https://medium.com/@richardr39/using-angular-cli-to-serve-over-https-locally-70dab07417c8

Comment: Yes.  That was it.  I also noticed that Edge and Firefox were NOT doing it.  Once I looked more closely at the redirect, I did noticed the HSTS reason for the redirect.  I think I'll update the question title to be more about Chrome.

Comment: as a quick fix, clearing the cache DNS by chrome://net-internals/#dns